# iOS Push Notifications what happens when a user restores an install or migrates devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

On iOS I get a unique token once a user has agreed via the os dialogue to receive messages.

But what happens if the user removes the app and downloads it again, does the token remain the same?

Does this work differently if the user restores an device from itunes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**APNs can issue a new device token for a variety of reasons:**

- User installs your app on a new device
- User restores device from a backup
- User reinstalls the operating system
- Other system-defined
  events

For more info: [Apple Docs on device Token changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1)

I don't know for what purpose you asked this question but below is a gentle reminder.

> **IMPORTANT**
>
> To protect user privacy, do not use device tokens to identify user
>   devices.

Comment: Thanks, I wish to know if a user has two ipads, where both are restored from the same itunes backup, would they both have the same token, and if so what happens when one message is sent? However from your link it seems that tokens are specific to a device and app pair.

Comment: No they both have different tokens. Even though they restored from same iTunes backup, it will create new token for each iPAD

Comment: APNS depends only on device token to send the messages. The device token is like identifying a particular device. It's used to be unique for device initially but due to privacy reasons, the apple doesn't want it to be an identifiable marker for the device. It started generating and changing device tokens on various scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate create a `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method, it will autocomplete when you import the `UserNotifications` framework. This will return a device token, simply send the new device token to your backend or wherever manages your remote notifications.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
   // send deviceToken to backend
}
```